# What is a basic textbook to studying symmetric spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I want to study basic properties of symmetric spaces.

What is a basic textbook?

Comment: It would help people to give better answers if you said a bit about your background or existing knowledge, e.g. Lie group theory, Riemannian geometry, PDEs, or whatever

Comment: Someone is going to mention Helgason's...

Comment: ...and to feel guilty immediately afterwards

Comment: What's wrong with Helgason? :)


Comment: Helgason is awesome, but not really "basic"...

Comment: There is a chapter about symmetric spaces in the book of J. Jost "Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis", it is quite basic and elementary.

Comment: A nice place to look at is Takashi Sakai's book "Riemannian Geometry", chapter IV section 6. It's not too much material (about 15 pages) but it covers the basics well and has references to places with the more advanced results.

Comment: What little I know about symmetric spaces is largely from Cheeger and Ebin's classic textbook.

Answer (score 2):

I do not now really elementary text, but for the non-positively curved ones you can have a look at Eberlein's *Geometry of nonpositively curved manifolds* (Chicago Lectures in Mathematics, University of Chicago Press, 1996).

By the way, I do not see why similar answers where stated as comments. Maybe you should repost them as answers so that one can be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite text is chapter 8 in Joseph Wolf's book "Spaces of constant curvature". 
I have a copy of the 5th edition, published by Publish of Perish, but a 6th edition 
by AMS Chelsea has recently come out. I don't claim it is an easy read, you need to work a lot on the details, but it gets to the point very efficiently. Perhaps it is fair to say that one can use it as a guide and complement the arguments as needed using the books of Helgason and Loos (2nd volume).

In particular, the classification of symmetric spaces is done in a rather elementary way, up to the case of involutions of $E_6$ which requires a bit of theory of roots (this part is best looked up in Loos' book).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the chapter in the second volume of Kobayashi-Nomizu; both volumes are written in a reader friendly manner, and normally proofs are well detailed with precise references to the previous used results. 
Helgason is quite tough I think.
Neither of these two are geometric enough in my opinion. The best for that are Loos's books (Symmetric space 1 and 2); these are my favourite !

Answer (score 0):

As a very basic reference, you might enjoy the easy-to-read Arvanitoyeorgos' book (see Chapter 6 for symmetric spaces): [An Introduction to Lie Groups and the Geometry of Homogeneous Spaces (Student Mathematical Library, V. 22)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821827782). Another good introductory text is the Chapter XI of [Kobayashi & Nomizu, Foundations of Differential Geometry, vol II.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471157325) Of course more advanced references are the ones mentioned before: Helgason, Wolf, Loos etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Metric rigidity theorems on Hermitian locally symmetric manifolds" by Ngaiming Mok is good, but may not be basic.